# Não possível converter JSON List para Array em Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, array

Estou com dificuldades de pegar os dados em javascript vindos de um json.

Para melhor explicar, os dados vem do banco de dados, assim:

//PHP

```
$rs = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id_acao as id, text FROM acoes");
$data = array();
if (mysqli_num_rows($rs) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)){
        $data[] =  $row;            
    }
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

Isso Está me retornando o seguinte (como uma string) :

> [{"id":"1","text":"bla bla bla"},{"id":"9","text":"bla bla bla"}]

Ou seja, ele retorna uma lista e não uma JsonString.
Na pagina que recebe não consigo convertê-lo para acessar os dados..

Assim:

```
var data = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText[0]);
```

ou assim (como vi em alguns foruns o uso do [].concat)

```
var data = JSON.parse(([].concat(ajax.responseText))[0]);
```

dá o mesmo erro.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Só consegui converter o  mesmo para um objecto, fazendo isso:

```
var data =  [].concat(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(ajax.responseText)));
```

Mas ao tentar acessá-lo com

```
var valor = data[0];
```

ou até mesmo com

```
var valor = data[0]['text'];
```

está me retornando um tipo (string) com todo o conteúdo do ajax!!

O que estou esquecendo ou fazendo errado? Obrigado a quem puder me ajudar!
At

UPDATE:  estava testando inserindo o valor diretamente em `JSON.parse` em vez de utilizar uma variável.

Por incrível que pareça, se eu digito exatamente o que há em `ajax.responseText` 
 dá certo. Se copio e colo o conteúdo, pelo console.log, dá erro.

// digitado , dá certo

```
var data = JSON.parse('[{"id":"1","text":"Windows XP"},{"id":"9","text":"não concluído"}]');
```

// copiado e colado do `console.log(ajax.responseText);`, dá erro

```
var data = JSON.parse('[{"id":"1","text":"Windows XP"},{"id":"9","text":"não concluído"}]');
```

Eu estou achando que é algum caractere especial e invisível que está no meio da string de `ajax.responseText`.

Eu testei ambos códigos acima , minhas ultimas duas citações, e deu certo ambas.

Comment: O que tem em `ajax.responseText` apenas?

Comment: Conforme acima, ajax.responseText há um tipo (string) com todo conteudo, exatamente igual à minha primeira citação acima em amarelo.

Comment: O pedido foi feito de Jquery ou de javascript normal?

Comment: @ThiagoYB então seu problema esta justamente em  `JSON.parse(ajax.responseText[0]);` que deveria se apenas `JSON.parse(ajax.responseText);`

Comment: Então quando faço  `var data = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText)`, ocorre o erro exatamente como acima.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de  muito pesquisar e testar, encontrei o problema!

Meus códigos PHP estavam infectados com um caractere invisível chamado "`ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE`"

Mesmo eu "settando" formatação correta no Notepad++ ele persistia.

Consegui Resolver com um script PHP que remove esse caractere invisível em todos meus arquivos PHP!

O mesmo pode ser encontrado no post gringo aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9773452

Espero que ajude outros com o mesmo problema!

At

Answer (score 1):

Partindo do principio que o `responseText` é exatamente `[{"id":"1","text":"bla bla bla"},{"id":"9","text":"bla bla bla"}]` o parse funciona bem:

```js
var ajax = {
  responseText: '[{"id":"1","text":"bla bla bla"},{"id":"9","text":"bla bla bla"}]'
};
     
var data = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText);

console.log(data);
console.log(data[0].text);
```

Se o pedido foi feito em JQuery e o tipo de dados já tiver sido especificado como `dataType='json'` então a resposta já vem em json e já não é possível nem necessário fazer o parse.

Aconselho também a confirmar através de `console.log` o valor exato que está a receber na resposta, para conseguir perceber de onde vem o problema.

Comment: Quando faço  `var data = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText)`, ocorre o erro exatamente como acima.Já quando coloco a string `[{..},{...}]` com oacima, copiando e colando da certo !!  - Consigo acessar com `data[0]['text']`

Comment: `console.log(ajax);` apresenta o que?